# why need to wait some second after enable GPS,to work?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I am making a small app, when the user clicks the button the app gets the users location and opens Google maps.

The problem is, if the users mobile doesn't have GPS enabled , then enables it and clicks the button again, this method will return `null`:

```
location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

When I wait after enabling GPS and then click the button, the method will work correctly and return the location.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> why need to wait some second after enable GPS,to work?

It's because when you enable GPS it'll fix position of **Satellite** and based on that you'll able to get Location.

Comment: but must be make my app work even if there was a delay, do you have any idea to solve this issue,

Comment: I have one idea. when you're GPS is searching for location at that time you'll get location using Network Provider....

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously a default behaviour, when you stop GPS and start it again, there is a small gap between start and stop, at that point, GPS will do its task, to get satellite data and after that it will provide you location. If we want to drive fast then we must need to start from 1st gear, same behaviour GPS doing.

Comment: what did you mean by  "1st gear"?

Comment: @arwa It was just example, that GPS spend some time between start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers mention above, the device will get the location after a while. If you are in the middle of a flow, you can show a `ProgressSpinner` and poll `getLastKnownLocation()` for x seconds to get a location.

Comment: did you mean must be add LocationListener? I Put getLastKnownLocation() in doInBackground but the same, it return null.

Comment: yes, you would need a LocationListener to ping the last known location.

Comment: how can I poll getLastKnownLocation() for x seconds to get a location?  getLastKnownLocation() take only one parameter "Provider".

Answer (score 0):

If you hadn't used GooglePlayServicesClient try this to get user location.

It is the fastest way to get current lat long.

For reference and code use the following link.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Hop i helped you.